# Yii2 не работает редирект

Tags: yii2, redirect

У меня есть контроллер поисковика друзей,вот код:

```
    <?php
namespace app\modules\User\controllers;

use app\models\Posts;
use app\modules\User\models\Friends;
use app\user;
use yii\web\Controller;
use Yii;

class FriendsController extends Controller{
    public $layout = '/friends/main';
    public function actionSearch(){
        if(isset($_POST['Button'])){
            echo $_POST['Button'];die();
        }
    return $this->render('search');
    }
    public function actionView(){
        if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
            return $this->goHome();
        }else{
            if(Yii::$app->request->get('page')){
                $id=Yii::$app->request->get('page');
                if($id!=Yii::$app->user->identity->id){
                    return $this->render('view',['id'=>$id]);
                }else{
                    return $this->redirect('/profile/index/');
                }

            }else{
                return $this->redirect('/profile/index/');
            }

        }
    }
    public function actionRequest(){
        if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
            return $this->goHome();
        }
        $id=Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        $allUserRequest=Friends::find()->where(['idUser'=>$id])->all();
        $check=1;
        if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
            $i=0;
            $id_friend= $_POST['Data'];
            $hisRequest=Friends::find()->where(['and',['idFriend'=>$id],['idUser'=>$id_friend],['count'=>0]])->all();
            $mineRequest=Friends::find()->where(['and',['idFriend'=>$id_friend],['idUser'=>$id],['count'=>0]])->all();
            $isFriend=Friends::find()->where(['or',['and',['idUser'=>$id],['idFriend'=>$id_friend],['count'=>1]],['and',['idUser'=>$id_friend],['idFriend'=>$id],['count'=>1]]])->all();
            foreach ($isFriend as $item){
                $i=$i+1;
            }
            if($c=$_POST['Action']){
                if($isFriend){
if($c==1){
    $delete=Friends::find()->where(['or',['and',['idUser'=>$id],['idFriend'=>$id_friend],['count'=>1]],['and',['idUser'=>$id_friend],['idFriend'=>$id],['count'=>1]]])->one();
    $delete->delete();

}

                }
                elseif($hisRequest){
                    $hisRequest=Friends::find()->where(['and',['idFriend'=>$id],['idUser'=>$id_friend],['count'=>0]])->one();
                    $hisRequest->count="1";
                    $hisRequest->save();

                }
                elseif($mineRequest){
echo $c;

                }
                else{
                    if($id_friend!=Yii::$app->user->identity->id){
                        if($check==1){

                            $request=new Friends();
                            $request->idUser=Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
                            $request->idFriend=$id_friend;
                            if($request->save()) {
                                $u=\app\models\User::find()->where(['id'=>$id_friend])->one();
                                echo $c;
                                echo "Friend request to"." ".$u->name." "."send";
                            }
                        }else echo $c."Request is alredy send";


                    }else echo $c."You cant add own page";
                }
            }

            }



    }
    public function actionRequests(){
        $requests=Friends::find()->where(['and',['idFriend'=>Yii::$app->user->identity->id],['count'=>0]])->all();

        return $this->render('requests',['requests'=>$requests]);
    }
    public function actionAjax(){
        if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
            return $this->goHome();
        }
            $id=Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
            if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
                $dataSearch=$_POST['Data'];
               $count= iconv_strlen($dataSearch);
                if($dataSearch){
                    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
                    if($dataSearch[$i]==" "){

                        $dataSearch2=substr($dataSearch,$i+1);
                        $dataSearch=substr($dataSearch,0,$i);

                    }else{
                    }

                }}

               if($dataSearch2){
                   $searchUser= \app\models\User::find()->where(['and',['like','name',$dataSearch],['like','surname',$dataSearch2]])->orWhere(['and',['like','name',$dataSearch2],['like','surname',$dataSearch]])->all();
               }else
               { $searchUser= \app\models\User::find()->where(['like','name',$dataSearch])->orWhere(['like','surname',$dataSearch])->all();};
                if($searchUser){
                    echo "<div id=\"data\">";
                    echo "<div class='row'>";
                    foreach ($searchUser as $item){

                        $hisRequest=Friends::find()->where(['and',['idFriend'=>$id],['idUser'=>$item->id],['count'=>0]])->all();
                        $mineRequest=Friends::find()->where(['and',['idFriend'=>$item->id],['idUser'=>$id],['count'=>0]])->all();
                        $isFriend=Friends::find()->where(['or',['and',['idUser'=>$id],['idFriend'=>$item->id],['count'=>1]],['and',['idUser'=>$item->id],['idFriend'=>$id],['count'=>1]]])->all();
                        if($isFriend){
                            $prm="Delete";
                            $c=1;
                        }elseif($mineRequest){
                            $prm="Request is send";
                            $c=2;
                        }elseif($hisRequest){
                            $prm="Add";
                            $c=3;
                        }elseif($item->id==$id){
                            $prm="My page";
                            $c=4;
                        }else{
                            $prm="Send request";
                            $c=5;
                        }
                        echo " <div class=\"col-sm-6 col-md-4\">
        <div class=\"thumbnail\">
            <img src=../../../$item->img alt=\"...\"  style='height: 250px; width:auto;'>
            <div class=\"caption\">
                <h3>$item->name</h3>
                <p>$item->surname</p>
                <p><button class=\"btn btn-info btn-lg\" type=\"button\" id='$item->id' data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#myModal\" onclick='addRequest($item->id,$c)'>$prm</button> <a href=\"view?page=$item->id\" class=\"btn btn-default\" role=\"button\">View page</a></p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>";
                    }
                echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                }else {
                    echo "<div id='data'>";
                    echo "No result";
                    echo "</div>";
                }
            }

    }
    public function actionIndex(){
        if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
            return $this->goHome();
        }
        $friends = Friends::find()->where(['and',['idUser'=>Yii::$app->user->identity->id],['count'=>1]])->all();
        $friendsR= Friends::find()->where(['and',['idFriend'=>Yii::$app->user->identity->id],['count'=>1]])->all();

        return $this->render('index',['friends'=>$friends,'friendsR'=>$friendsR]);
    }
    public function actionRcheck(){
        if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
            return $this->goHome();
        }
       if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
           if(isset($_POST['Accept'])){
              $val=$_POST['Accept'];
               $acceptUser=Friends::find()->where(['and',['idFriend'=>Yii::$app->user->identity->id],['idUser'=>$val]])->one();
               if($acceptUser){
                   $acceptUser->count=1;
                   if($acceptUser->save()){
                       echo "Request accepted";
                   }

               }

           }
       }
    }

}
?>
```

Не раотает редирект в экшине View, когда срабативает редирект просто пустая страница без ничего в адресной строке остаеться тот же путь что был задан до редректа

Answer (score 1):

Поменяйте

```
return $this->redirect('/profile/index/');
```

На

```
 return $this->redirect(['profile/index/']);
```

Comment: Тот же результат

Comment: Попробуйте без слэша. Поправил ответ.